# Saving polygon coordinates into MySQL

Tags: coordinates, mysql, leaflet-draw

I am currently building a housing complex mapping in my regency with **PHP**, **Leaflet.draw** and **MySQL** to store the data.

My problem is, how to save the polygon coordinates into MySQL?

I am extremely new to GIS and I hope the answers is not too confusing.

Comment: Have you tried MySQL spatial data types: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql-spatial?tab=Newest

Comment: PHP and MySQL can use WKT (Well Known Text) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23900/how-to-add-polygon-in-mysql-database